# How to test In-App-Purchase

Tags: android, testing, in-app-purchase

I am using In-app purchase in my android app. I have already added testing account on google play developer console but when i am purchasing showing redeem option and credit card option. How can i test my in-app purchase.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing have changed, there should be note, that creadit card is required for registration process but while developement money won't be taken.

[image]

For more see:
http://help.gamesalad.com/gamesalad-cookbook/7-using-pro-features/7-03-adding-in-app-purchases-iap/7-03-2-setting-up-iap-for-google-play/

Comment: But in my case showing "Please tap "Continue" to add a payment method or redeem a code to complete your purchase".

Comment: Is Your phone (main account in Your phone) added to tester group?
If yes, then You shouldn't be charged after pressing Continue.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can upload your signed APK in play store in ALPHA mode and then pay using your credit card or debit card, google will payback your money within 48hrs(don't know exact time), Or you can use test SKU **"android.test.purchase"** and then you can check your purchase state.